# grails 3 dependency service gradle

Tags: parsing, grails, intellij-idea, service

I want to ask you how to create a service with these code:

```
@Grab(group='org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup', module='tagsoup', version='1.2')
def parser = new XmlSlurper(new org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser())

def page = parser.parse('http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/luna/SR1a/eclipse-jee-luna-SR1a-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz')

println page.depthFirst().find { it.text() == 'North America'}
println page.depthFirst().find { it.text().contains('North America')}
```

So the idea is to create a service with similar functionallity.

I tries several approaches and non of them worked.
Here is one of them:
1) replace @Grab by :

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:1.2
```

in **build.gradle**

2) adding in the service: import org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup or import org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.*

3) added new repository:         mavenCentral()

4) adding line in **project.iml** :

```
<orderEntry type="library" name="Gradle: org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:1.2" level="project" />
```

What I'm missing?

Tech info:
grails 3.0, Intellij 15, services create by grails create-service

I've took the dependency value from:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup/tagsoup/1.2
gradle section

Comment: have you tried from jcenter()?

Comment: Hi. No I've read something about it but the information was not enough and the solution was incomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first approach for referencing dependencies is correct in a gradle / grails project.

After that you should be able to load `new org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser()` just fine, if it's in one of the repositories. For example it's available in mavenCentral (which you add in 3). The import only helps to reduce clutter so that you don't need the fully-qualified class name to use the class. You probably shouldn't manage the **project.iml** by hand.

Could it be that only IntelliJ say there is a error but if you execute it, it just works fine?

After adding dependencies in **build.gradle** you need to tell IntelliJ to sync the project definition:

1. Go to the **Gradle Tool Window** (View => Tool Windows => Gradle)
2. Click on **Refresh all Gradle projects** (blue circular arrows)

After that the Intellij project definition (project.iml) and the Gradle project are synchronized and IntelliJ should know about the dependency.

Comment: Yes! This solved the problem. I was relying only on: **clean** and **compile refresh-dependencies** which seems that was not enough. Thank you.